# Bootstrap4, Webpack, Navbar toggle button

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, webpack

I have a react app using bootstrap 4.0.0-beta.2. I configure bootstrap in webpack as described on their web site [Webpack-Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/webpack/).

This is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
entry: ["babel-polyfill",'./src/app.js'],
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
},
module: {
    rules: [{
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/
    }, {
        test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
        use: [
            'style-loader',
            'css-loader',
            'sass-loader'
        ]
    }]
},
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
        Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
    })
]
}
```

I install jQuery and popper as required by bootstrap 4.0.0-beta.2.

I have a navigation component that uses bootstrap navbar. See below:

```
const Navigation = () => {
return (
    <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top">
        <h1 className="navbar-brand">My App</h1>
        <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <div className="navbar-nav">
            <li><NavLink exact to="/" activeClassName="active" activeStyle={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Menu 1</NavLink></li>
            <li><NavLink exact to="/classement" activeClassName="active" activeStyle={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Menu 2</NavLink></li>
            <li><NavLink exact to="/calendrier" activeClassName="active" activeStyle={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Menu 3</NavLink></li>
            <li><NavLink exact to="/archives" activeClassName="active" activeStyle={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Archives</NavLink></li>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
)
};
```

My problem is that the toggle button is not working. When I am on small devices, the toggle button appears, but, when I click on it, nothing happens. I can't have my menu on small devices.

I read some responses about this issue, but all the solutions suggest, when your are using cdn, to put the jQuery script tag before all the other scripts. But I am not using cdn, I am including Bootstrap in my project using Webpack 2.

In my webpack entry, I also tried to add the jQuery file before all other files, like this:

```
module.exports = {
entry: ["babel-polyfill",'script-loader!jquery/dist/jquery.min.js','./src/app.js'],
...
```

but the problem is still there.

Do you have any idea on how to fix this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I finaly found what was the problem.
In my main file **app.js**, I only imported the style part of bootstrap:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

I have to import also the js part of bootstrap

```
// Bootstrap
 import 'bootstrap';
 import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

So the final configuration of bootstrap using webpack is :

1. webpack.config.js

   ```
   const path = require('path');
   const webpack = require('webpack');

   module.exports = {
   entry: ["babel-polyfill",'./src/app.js'],
   output: {
     path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
     filename: 'bundle.js'
   },
   module: {
   rules: [{
       loader: 'babel-loader',
       test: /\.js$/,
       exclude: /node_modules/
   }, {
       test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
       use: [
           'style-loader',
           'css-loader',
           'sass-loader'
       ]
   }]
   },
   plugins: [
   new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
       $: 'jquery',
       jQuery: 'jquery',
       'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
       Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
   })
   ]
   }
   ```
2. In the main js file (app.js): import both, js part and style part of bootstrap

   ```
   // Bootstrap
   import 'bootstrap';
   import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
   ```

Answer (score 0):

As of "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",

Once Bootstrap is installed through npm/yarn

You just need to import bootstrap as following

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

There is no need for configuration in Webpack. Once you import bootstrap JS, it automatically looks for jQuery in node_modules.

You are done!!